# jQuery scrollbar doesn't work in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrollbar

I created a dynamic div using jquery and want the div's scroll bar to start off at the bottom of the screen while the page loads and then whenever new information comes it it will automatically go down. My code seems to be working fine on firefox and internet explorer but not chrome and I'm not really sure why.

```
$(function(){
    $("#divID").scrollTop($("#divID")[0].scrollHeight);

    $("#divID").scroll(function(){
        if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() === $(this).outerHeight())
        {
            //added alert here because i know the scrolling down code works...
            alert(1);
        }
    });​
}
```

I've looked everywhere and tried many different ways to scroll the bar down but to no avail, chrome just doesn't seem to want this to work.

I would appreciate any advice on how i could fix this.

edit: Here's a demo  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DgYcY/50/)

edit again: Sorry I'm bad at explaining myself, doing my best, the message box has to appear when the screen loads.

Comment: Try using `$(this)[0].scrollTop`. And please post a demo if you have one.

Comment: @A.M.K here, try using this one firefox and chrome and see the difference.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DgYcY/50/)

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome 22, try using jQuery 1.8 and closing you CSS statement, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/YypSn/).

Comment: That's weird, I have version Version 22 too and it's not working...

Comment: Hmm could it be a setting somewhere or something? I tried clearing browser data, no luck... Asked a friend of mine to test it on chrome, he has the same problem I do, so don't think it's just me... And to clarify the msgbox needs to show on when the screen loads, just making sure that's what I mean, I can't explain stuff easily.

Comment: Oh, that explains it, it's not firing because you haven't set the event listener until after you scroll initially, please see my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event isn't firing because you don't set the event listener until *after* you initially scroll, try this code:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/watWg/

jQuery:

```
$("#divID").scroll(function(){
    if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight())
    {
        alert(1);
    }
}).scrollTop($("#divID")[0].scrollHeight);​
```

Or, if you want, you can do it with plain JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/eJCnU/

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for your help. I'll try to remember that so that I don't ever make such a mistake again.

Comment: I'm updating my answer, you really don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: I made a mistake in my JQ-free demo, please reload it.

Comment: It should work, just watch out for what order you put things in.

Comment: Seems like jsfiddle is down so I'll check the javascript part later, quick  question what if I want the first line to run on load (the one that puts the scrollbar at the end) and I want to put the one that reads if the scrollbar is at the end in a function??

Comment: You'd need to call the function before you scroll the element down, unless you don't want the event listener to fire.